# Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to replace inside the DOM of a page using the replace() in javascript

In the source code I want to replace:

```
<div class="topbar">Bookmark Us</div>
```

to

```
<div class="topbar"><span class="larger-font">Bookmark Us</span></div>
```

When a Google Chrome extenstion is **on** the matched website of a URL and it will do the above.

Any page that matches:

```
http://www.domain.com/support.php
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about how Chrome triggers its extensions, but I can tell you about page content manipulation.

To wrap all the child content of a `topbar` div in plain JavaScript:

```
var topbars= document.getElementsByClassName('topbar');
for (var i= topbars.length; i-->0;) {
    var span= document.createElement('span');
    span.className= 'larger-font';
    while (topbars[i].firstChild)
        span.appendChild(topbars[i].firstChild);
    topbars[i].appendChild(span);
}
```

(getElementsByClassName is a relatively new API, but Chrome 3 supports it. For each matching element, move all its children into a new span element, and put that span inside the div.)

Or using jQuery, if you don't mind dragging a great big framework in:

```
$('.topbar').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().wrapAll('<span class="larger-font"></span>');
});
```

Whilst you *can* operate on HTML as strings, using something like:

```
for (var i= topbars.length; i-->0;)
    topbars[i].innerHTML= '<span class="larger-font">'+topbars[i].innerHTML+'</span>';
```

this should in general be avoided, as you will be serialising and re-parsing the entire node contents of the div, in the process destroying any non-serialisable content like JavaScript references, event listeners and form field values.

Comment: +1 for being a correct answer, and for the `i-->0;` bit in the `for` loop. It's obviously simple, and nice in its suggestion that `i` reaches `0`, yet I've never seen or thought of using a `for` condition clause that way.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). Set it to be triggered on the URL(s) you want in the manifest, then use Bobince's code to actually apply the manipulations.